# Why javascript error stack for just one loop?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Why error stack even for n = 1?

```js
function f(n) {
  const f1 = f(n - 1);
  const f2 = f(n - 2);
  return n == 0 ? 0 : (n == 1 ? 1 : f1 + f2);

}

console.log(f(1));
```

Comment: Well you're always running the function in the first two lines so you need to put your base case conditional before that

Comment: JS is an eagerly executed language, not a lazy one, where expressions are evaluated only when their result is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your base case conditional is after you perform a recursive call, you'll always hit the first line, the function will call itself, then the first line will be run, the function will call itself, forever. You need your base case conditional statement before any unconditional recursion (note that I've literally replaced `f1` and `f2` with their definitions below):

```js
function f(n) {
  return n == 0 ? 0 : (n == 1 ? 1 : f(n - 1) + f(n - 2));
}

console.log(f(1));
```

This is probably a bit neater (handle base cases individually, then return the sum of the two recursive components):

```js
function f(n) {
  if (n == 0) return 0;
  if (n == 1) return 1;
  const f1 = f(n - 1);
  const f2 = f(n - 2);
  return f1 + f2;
}

console.log(f(1));
```

Comment: Wouldn't `if (n <= 0) return 0;` be slightly better?

Comment: @KenY-N That's not OP's code - I fixed their problem, not any underlying logic flaws in the code (a CodeReview question, not SO question).

Comment: @KenY-N not needed in context of fibonacci formula